# If a character has a higher horizontal jump speed than movement speed, is their jump paused midair once their movement is finished?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

If a character has a higher horizontal jump speed than movement speed, is their jump paused mid-air once their movement is finished?

Or, do they continue moving? If so, what stops a player from jumping everywhere instead of walking?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.